# using iTextpdf parse the HTML to PDF getting java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, itext

I try to execute this code its getting `java.lang.NullPointerException`

```
writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("D:\\Test.pdf"));
document.open();
XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, new FileInputStream("D:\\work\\iTextPDF\\index.html"));
document.close();
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException   at
 com.itextpdf.tool.xml.net.FileRetrieveImpl.read(FileRetrieveImpl.java:182)
    at
 com.itextpdf.tool.xml.net.FileRetrieveImpl.processFromHref(FileRetrieveImpl.java:150)
    at
 com.itextpdf.tool.xml.css.StyleAttrCSSResolver.addCssFile(StyleAttrCSSResolver.java:289)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.head.Link.start(Link.java:78)     at
 com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.AbstractTagProcessor.startElement(AbstractTagProcessor.java:136)
    at
 com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.html.HtmlPipeline.open(HtmlPipeline.java:96)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorker.startElement(XMLWorker.java:165)
    at
 com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.startElement(XMLParser.java:320)
    at
 com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.state.SelfClosingTagState.process(SelfClosingTagState.java:70)
    at
 com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.parseStream(XMLParser.java:184)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:138)
    at
 com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.parseXHtml(XMLWorkerHelper.java:181)
    at
 org.open.word.test.TestOpenWord.convertHTMLtoPDFCase2(TestOpenWord.java:55)
    at org.open.word.test.TestOpenWord.main(TestOpenWord.java:19)
```

Comment: Is your html file using external css? Looks like this file will not be found

Comment: Yes i am using **CSS** file